# AWS SDK Android file uploading failed on S3 Bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the `AWS SDK` for android. I tired to get the sample "`S3_uploader`" working but when i run it i get a error .i have include the jar by adding it to the path and by copying and pasting the jar file into the `libs` folder. Nothing works. can anyone please help me?

Comment: the errorr i get "java.lang NoClassDefFoundError : com amazonaws.sercices.s3.AmazonS3Client"....

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the jar file to the libs folder, you also need to include it in your Java Build Path.  Assuming that you're using eclipse, this is how you would add it:

1. Right click on project in the project explorer, and click on properties
2. On the left menu, click on Java Build Path and then click the button "Add Jars"
3. Select the jar you added in the libs folder.

After pressing ok, you should try rebuilding the project and it shouldn't give the `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Like Bob said, you would need to increase the heap size to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider looking at [this post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20QCGGQZLH23U/Running-AWS-SDK-for-Android-samples-in-Eclipse-with-ADT-v22) on our Mobile Development blog for how to use the samples with the latest versions of Eclipse with ADT.

Note, you may need to expand the memory available to eclipse. The [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) has directions for increasing the heap size available to Eclipse to overcome memory related errors.

Comment: this one worked for me. but why eclipse didn't try to auto increase by its own

Comment: @kifcaliph Eclipse is itself a java application and is beholden to the limits of the JVM, and as such is not permitted to increase it's own memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using "libs\aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar" but when using  "aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-core.jar" + other service JAR then it works fine, for more info about aws-jars:

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JXN6FGS5Y2L1/Understanding-the-JARs-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android